# Weird behaviour with OpenGL Uniform Buffers on OSX

Tags: macos, opengl

I am having some weird behaviour with uniform buffers in my hobby OpenGL4.1 engine.

On windows everything works fine (both Intel and Nvidia GPUs) but on my MacBook (also Intel) this isn't working.

So to explain what is happening on OSX: if I hardcode all my Uniform Buffer variables in the actual fragment shader code then I am able to render perfectly fine but if I set them back to the variables - I get nothing.

Had a look at the OpenGL state using apitrace and all the variables values are perfect so I am a bit confused as to what is going on here.

I am hoping this is just a code bug and not some underlying issue with the drivers.

Below is the fragment shader code where if I hardcode all the DirectionLight variables everything works fine.

```
#version 410

struct DirectionalLightData
{
  vec4 Colour;
  vec3 Direction;
  float Intensity;
};

layout(std140) uniform ObjectBuffer
{
  mat4 Model;
};

layout(std140) uniform FrameBuffer
{
  mat4 Projection;
  mat4 View;  
  DirectionalLightData DirectionalLight;
  vec3 ViewPos;
};

uniform sampler2D PositionMap;
uniform sampler2D NormalMap;
uniform sampler2D AlbedoSpecMap;

layout(location = 0) in vec2 TexCoord;

out vec4 FinalColour;

float CalcDiffuseContribution(vec3 lightDir, vec3 normal)
{
  return max(dot(normal, -lightDir), 0.0f);
}

float CalcSpecularContribution(vec3 lightDir, vec3 viewDir, vec3 normal, float specularExponent)
{
  vec3 reflectDir = reflect(lightDir, normal);
  vec3 halfwayDir = normalize(lightDir + viewDir);
  return pow(max(dot(normal, halfwayDir), 0.0f), specularExponent);
}


float CalcDirectionLightFactor(vec3 viewDir, vec3 lightDir, vec3 normal)
{
  float diffuseFactor = CalcDiffuseContribution(lightDir, normal);
  float specularFactor = CalcSpecularContribution(normal, viewDir, normal, 1.0f);
  return diffuseFactor * specularFactor;
}


void main()
{
  vec3 position = texture(PositionMap, TexCoord).rgb;
  vec3 normal = texture(NormalMap, TexCoord).rgb;
  vec3 albedo = texture(AlbedoSpecMap, TexCoord).rgb;

  vec3 viewDir = normalize(ViewPos - position);
  float directionLightFactor = CalcDirectionLightFactor(viewDir, DirectionalLight.Direction, normal) * DirectionalLight.Intensity;

  FinalColour.rgb = albedo * directionLightFactor * DirectionalLight.Colour.rgb;
  FinalColour.a = 1.0f * DirectionalLight.Colour.a;
}
```

Here is the order of where I update and bind the UBO (I have pulled these from apitrace as there is too much code to copy paste here):

```
glGetActiveUniformBlockName(5, 0, 255, NULL, FrameBuffer);
glGetUniformBlockIndex(5, FrameBuffer) = 0;
glGetActiveUniformBlockName(5, 1, 255, NULL, ObjectBuffer);
glGetUniformBlockIndex(5, ObjectBuffer) = 1;

glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 1);
glMapBufferRange(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, 172,GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT);
memcpy(0x10b9f8000, [binary data, size = 172 bytes], 172);
glUnmapBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER);

glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, 2);
glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 1, 1);

glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 2);
glMapBufferRange(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, 64, GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT);
memcpy(0x10b9f9000, [binary data, size = 64 bytes], 64);
glUnmapBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER);

glUniformBlockBinding(5, 1, 0);
glUniformBlockBinding(5, 0, 1);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

Note that the FrameBuffer UBO has ID 1 and ObjectBuffer UBO has ID 2

Comment: Just another thing I have noticed... if I change the order of the variables in the Uniform Buffer I can vastly different results. This tells me that it may be a byte offset issue within the buffer itself.

Comment: I see no problems with alignment. But in shader, the resulting color is affected only by `albedo` and no uniform buffers are used. I run your shader with `FinalColour.rgb = albedo * directionLightFactor;` and it works correctly.

Comment: Please include the code for filling the UBO and also binding it.  There are a couple of potential issues.

Comment: @Asaq Sorry I seem to have copied the wrong shader code in the example - I have fixed it.

Comment: @derhass I had added the OpenGL calls that update UBO.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you are using std140 layout your data members should be byte aligned so you cannot mix vec4 and vec3 or float keep all variables mat4 and vec4 else dnt use std140 layout and in application side calculate ubo alignment and offsets of your variables on ubo and set values. See usage of GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER_OFFSET_ALIGNMENT. 
As experiment change all variables to mat4 and vec4 and see your issue should go away.

If you did not use the std140 layout for a block, you will need to query the byte offset for each uniform within the block. The OpenGL specification explains the storage of each of the basic types, but not the alignment between types. Struct members, just like regular uniforms, each have a separate offset that must be individually queried.

Comment: That might be the problem. 
On windows GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER_OFFSET_ALIGNMENT is 16.
On my MacBook it is 256.

Comment: Yes you can do quick experiment I told you just change all members of UBO to vec4 or mat4 basically aligned to your offset and it should work as is.

Comment: Changed all vec3 and float to vec4 but still it does not work.
The weird thing is in ApiTrace, it shows all the correct values so it should be working.

Comment: Can you post updated code with vec4 only? Also dont use create seperate DirectionalLightData just yse directly data here just to simplify.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days of digging I seem to have found the issue.

I was not calling glBindBufferBase() after binding a different shader program.

Such a silly mistake caused me so much grief.

Thanks everyone for the help.